# Python lists comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
string = "Hello 12345 World"
numbers = [x for x in string if x.isdigit()]
print numbers

>> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Another example:

```
>>> noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
>>> primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
>>> print primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

What is confusing me is the `x for x` part. I've seen it a few places before but unsure what it means. Could someone provide more examples and explanation for these examples?

Answer (score 3):

These constructs are called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

**Simple example**

`[x for x in iterable]` literally means "for every element in iterable, add that element to newly created list" and is equivalent to

```
new_list = []
for x in iterable:
    new_list.append(x)
```

Line-by-line explanation:

```
Loop                             List comprehension
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
new_list = []                    [x for x in iterable]
for x in iterable:               [x for x in iterable]
    new_list.append(x)           [x for x in iterable]
```

**A bit more complex example**

`[int(x) for x in string if x.isdigit()]` can be read as "for every element in iterable, add the result of applying `int` to the element to newly created list if `x.isdigit()`".

Line-by-line explanation:

```
Loop                             List comprehension
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
numbers = []                     [int(x) for x in string if x.isdigit()]
for x in string:                 [int(x) for x in string if x.isdigit()]
    if x.isdigit():              [int(x) for x in string if x.isdigit()]
        numbers.append(int(x))   [int(x) for x in string if x.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 2):

> `numbers = [x for x in string if x.isdigit()]` means itemize each x in string if x is a digit

It translates to

```
   numbers = []
    for x in string:
        if x.isdigit()
           numbers.append(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

it's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is used to build a list using an expression instead of more than 3 statements.

```
numbers = [x for x in string if x.isdigit()]
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
numbers = []
for x in string:
    if x.isdigit():
        numbers.append(x)
```

then

```
noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
noprimes = []
for i in range(2, 8): 
    for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
        noprimes.append(j)
```

and

```
primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
primes = []
for x in range(2, 50):
    if x not in noprimes
        primes.append(x)
```

but written as a one liner.

---

N.B.: You can also build a generator:

```
(x for x in range(0, 10))
```

a set:

```
{x for x in range(0, 10)}
```

and a dictionary:

```
{(x, x) for x in range(0, 10)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [x for x in string if x.isdigit()]
```

The list comprehension above is similar to the following traditional code:

```
numbers = []

for x in string:
    if x.isdigit():
        numbers.append(x)
```